# Dynamic SQL with update and select

Tags: sql-server

I know I am likely missing a basic punctuation issue, but I can't figure it out...

I am passing a table and date field to an UPDATE SET x=(SELECT...) statement and it isn't working correctly. The exact code is:

```
SET @sqlCommand= 'UPDATE FDT_Needed 
                          SET Need=(SELECT 0 
                          FROM '+@table +'  
                          INNER JOIN FD__MASTERDUEDATES b on b.OP__DOCID='+@table+'.OP__DOCID 
                          WHERE '''+@DateField+''' IS NULL 
                          AND b.DATEDUE IS NOT NULL)'

EXEC (@sqlCommand)
```

When I "SELECT Need FROM FDT_Needed" I get Null, however, if I write the same sql code above with the same test data I am using (not using dynamic SQL) I get 0. Any thoughts? I can add additional info if that is helpful.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't seem right:

```
WHERE '''+@DateField+''' IS NULL
```

That will result in:

```
WHERE 'someStringGoesHere' IS NULL
```

which is comparing a *string literal* to `NULL`, which will always be false. I'm guessing `@DateField` is a column name and you instead intended:

```
WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(@DateField) + ' IS NULL
```

Side note: Consider calling `QUOTENAME` on `@table` as well unless you're absolutely sure it's safe.

Comment: First off, Thank you!!! This fixed the issue right off the bat. I'm definitely a novice when it comes to dynamic sql in particular and self taught in sql in general. I've never used quotename before and am curious of the benefits to using it with "@table" vs just using "@table" - and are you referring in the where clause or the From line? I took my basic format from some other stackflow answers and am never sure if I'm using the best approach.Thank you!

Comment: @Julian Both. Dynamic SQL is powerful but is also rather dangerous. In this case an evil `@table` is most likely going to just result in an error, but for a simple example consider what happens if you did not escape @DateField (with `QUOTENAME`) and set `@DateField = '1=1 OR NULL'`. This will result in a new query `...WHERE 1=1 OR NULL IS NULL AND b.DATEDUE IS NOT NULL`. Not quite "evil" *per se* but certainly annoying.

Comment: yeah, more like what if the query string passed in @table = ' Needed; DROP TABLE  NEEDED --' :D i'd still go with ORM's specially if available.

Comment: @lc, @ken lacoste. Thank you both for the input, I'll be going with `QUOTENAME` from here on out

Comment: @lc Do you mind if I ask another related question of you instead of creating another thread? I'm not sure of the customs on stackoverflow yet and don't want to do anything improper. I'm thinking I'm having a similar issue.

Comment: @lc  I'm using the following code: `DECLARE @SqlCommand2 NVARCHAR(MAX)
      , @LastDate DATETIME 

     SET @SqlCommand2= N'SELECT MAX('+QUOTENAME(@DateField)+')=@LDate 
          FROM '+QUOTENAME(@table)+'
          WHERE PgmAdmissionKey = '+CAST(@PgmAdmissionKey AS VARCHAR(7))
   
     EXEC sp_executesql @SqlCommand2, N'@DateField VARCHAR(100), @table VARCHAR(100), @PgmAdmissionKey INT, @LDate DATETIME OUTPUT', @DateField=@DateField, @Table=@table, @PgmAdmissionKey=@PgmAdmissionKey, @LDate=@LastDate OUTPUT
     SELECT @LastDate` and I'm getting an "Incorrect syntax near '='" message.

Comment: @lc I tried changing the where to `WHERE PgmAdmissionKey = '''+CAST(@PgmAdmissionKey AS VARCHAR(7))+''''` and got the same message. Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: hmm, isn't it that you're setting your select to @LDate? Maybe what would fix this is N'SELECT @LDate =  MAX('+QUOTENAME(@DateField)+ ') FROM '

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @sqlCommand= 'UPDATE FDT_Needed 
                          SET Need=(SELECT TOP(1) 0 
                          FROM '+@table +'  
                          INNER JOIN FD__MASTERDUEDATES b on b.OP__DOCID='+@table+'.OP__DOCID 
                          WHERE '+@DateField+' IS NULL 
                          AND b.DATEDUE IS NOT NULL)'

EXEC (@sqlCommand)
```

Comment: And what do you suppose that would do? Consider adding some *words* to your answer.

Comment: @DateField should have single colon---> '

Comment: Muks fixed the WHERE clause of the query. You can't put apostrophe around a column name. And TOP(1) statement would increase performance.